# Add a class to my element with respect to my textarea height (or rows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea element which is not have any specify height or row..

I want to add a simple class name to one of my elements **When** my textarea element has for example 137px height (or for example 5 rows).
and when it returned to his default height, the class name get removed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll ned to use javascript/jquery to get the height of the element and then add or remove the class accordingly.  For example:

```
if($('textarea').height() == 137) {
    $('textarea').addClass('className');
}else{
    $('textarea').removeClass('className');
}
```